# WP plugin svn checkout 429 error "Too many requests"

Tags: plugin-development

I've developed a wordpress plugin. It was approved. But I can't upload my code through SVN.

I've installed tortoise SVN, and when I checkout, svn server returned HTTP 429 'Too Many Requests'.

[image: Wordpress plugin svn error "Http 429 Too many Requests"]

In fact, I'd confirmed the plugin approval email so late, maybe 6 hours later from received time. And they said I have to upload within one hour.

What do I have to do now? I've emailed the support team. But no response. Maybe they are busy.
Could you please help me?

Comment: Unless someone's seen this before for the WordPress SVN server I don't think we can help, sorry - you do need to talk to WordPress's technical support. It might be worth trying a different SVN client from a different system too if you can, or from a different network in case this is an IP-related ban.

Comment: I've tried VPN, but also does not work. Do I have to upload it from amazon machine? or from linux OS?

Comment: OK, then it sounds like it's a problem with the server or your account. Either way I don't think we can help you. You'll probably have to wait for the WordPress support team to get back to you.